# iOS 10 Quicklook Memory Usage

Tags: ios, swift, ios10

When ill load some images to my QuicklookController, the used memory is never freed by the Memory Management. For Example:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let photoFile = photos[indexPath.row] as Photo
    currentFilePath = photoFile.filePath

    let preview = QLPreviewController()
    preview.dataSource = self
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(preview, animated: false)

}

func documentsDirectoryURL() -> NSURL {
    let manager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let URLs = manager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    return URLs[0]
}

func previewController(controller: QLPreviewController, previewItemAtIndex index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem {
    return documentsDirectoryURL().URLByAppendingPathComponent(currentFilePath)
}
```

Here ill load the image. Image size is about 200kbytes, with  size of about 2500x1250 Pixels. The Memory increased by about 10 Mbytes, BUT when ill close the Controller (Back Button) the memory is still used. So every click costs 10 Mbytes of additional RAM (Doesent matter if the image is the same, or a new one)

How can i force that the `QLPreviewController` should free the used memory?

Edit: Seems that this is already reported:

https://github.com/jcamiel/radars/blob/6b02382c08cdd9312df325a7a08ea9efeec5727b/28318213/radar.md

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/63020

Edit2:

Tested now with 2 iPad Pro 9.7

First, iOS 10.0.1 -> Memory increases as described above.
Second, iOS 9.3.5 -> No Memory issues

So it seems its really only a iOS 10 Bug...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be fixed with iOS 10.0.2